# How can I make the background of UICollection view as transparent without making the cells in it transparent in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view and of course I also have the cells in it. If in the property inspector I change the alpha of collection view to 0, the cells in it also become transparent. Is there a way to make the background transparent of the collection view only so the image behind it is visible?

Comment: ... click the cell and set a background color for it

Comment: I want to make the the background of it transparent without making the cell transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `UICollectionViewCell`'s background is defaulted to clear. Simply set a background colour for your cells either in interface builder or in a subclass using:

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.WhiteColor()
```

Comment: There's an image behind the collection view that I want to be made visible behind the cells. If I make it white then image behind would still not be visible.

Comment: @laser2302 you are not reading my answer. There are 2 controls in question here, the collectionView and its cells. The cells are by default set to clear. Set your collectionView to clear as you have been, then go to each of your cells and give them a background color, to overwrite the default setting of clear

Comment: Solved! I found out I was doing it wrong, I was setting it as Default instead of Clear Color. Thanks a lot buddy!

Answer (score 12):

using in Swift 3:

```
collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.withAlphaComponent(0)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can change the cell colour to clear and set the background to nil to see whats underneath the collectionView. Like this:

```
  collectionview.backgroundView = nil;
  collectionview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: this does not answer the OP's question

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin but this answers mine anyway.

Answer (score 3):

if you drop collection view opacity to 0 the whole collection view will be invisible. In your case you want to show collection view cell only so collection view **cell's** background view should be UIColor.clear either collection **view** background. Programmatically like this

```
    self.collectionView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

In my case i need to show chat log like this so i used that code

[my example case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Eg2p.png)

Answer (score 1):

In the UICollectionView set the background color to clearcolor in the attribute inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping `UICollectionView`'s Opacity to `0` from attribute inspector will make it transperent.

**P.S:**

*Bad practice, but will work.*